# My computer restarts and cant find my hdd

Tags: hard-drive, reboot

So, sometimes when i'm playing League of Legends or Diablo my computer will crash:

- I can still watch already loaded videos (youtube) for 1 or 2 minutes;
- I can still move the mouse pointer;
- I can't open new windows;
- I can't right click on the desktop;
- I can't turn the computer off

  Aside this, the Diablo/LoL window will freeze (no response), and will eventually restart after showing a blue screen very fast.

  When it restarts, it will ask for a valid boot, and i can't find my HDD at the boot menu. If i wait for 20-40 minutes, my HDD will be shown again.

  ASROCK H61M-HVS; Intel Core i3 2100; Hitachi HDP725050GLA360; NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 Ti; Windows 7

  ===========

  Already fixed. I just have to buy another HDD, cause every Hitachi DeathStar HDD crashes. Thank you anyway.

Comment: What is the make and wattage of your PSU?

Comment: Forget it, i discovered that this Hitachi is garbage, and it's the problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: That's odd. I run four of those Deskstars in a RAID and each has done around 40,000 hours of operational service. They're currently burning away at 49 degrees C, but they're not dead yet. Rugged little drives, they are.

Comment: Check the HDD cables!

Answer (score 1):

Nah, the "DeathStars" were the IBM GXP models which, among other things, had a nasty habit of head crashing. The model you have is the Hitachi made GST model which, while not perfect, has none of the design flaws that plagued the GXP's and are usually rated quite highly.

If you've had the HDD for less than 2 years, you may well have some other issue at hand that has caused it to fail and could potentially claim the life of it's replacement. It might be prudent to check things like your PSU and ventilation as both power issues and improper cooling can severely degrade the life of a hard drive.